# PostgreSQL bitmap heap scan takes long time

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have Case table which has almost 25,00,000 rows and 176 columns (mostly varchar)

```
select
    count(ca.id)
from
    salesforce.case ca
where
    ca.accountid = '001i000000E'    
    AND ca.createddate BETWEEN current_date - interval '6 months' AND current_date
```

I am trying to get number of records created for last 6 months for specific account. But when I look at the explain and analyze, I found that it first index scans all the records created in that timespan and index scans all records for that account and then does bitmap heap scan (which takes long time).

https://explain.depesz.com/s/8Lje

Is there any way we can make it faster?

Comment: 1,125.320 ms is one second on 25*10^6 rows 176 columns... bitmap heap scan goes over a million rows joining 200K, giving the result for 500K rows. And it takes one second - right?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index `ON ca(accountid, createddate)` that can be used for both conditions.

Given on the numbers in your explain output, it may be that PostgreSQL still uses a *bitmap index scan* because it thinks that is faster. You can try to lower `random_page_cost`, see if different plans are chosen and test which one is the fastest.